# Calculate column id with logic

Tags: c#, sql

I would like suggestions how to solve the following demand.

I have a table with three fields: EmployeeId, HireDate and DepartmentId.

The EmployeeId needs to be in the following format: yyyyddddxxxx
where:

```
  yyyy - is the year the employee was hired.
  dddd - DepartmentId.
  xxxx - running number for each department on each year.
```

Would this be best computed using sql or C#?
How do I calculate the 'xxxx' part?
I can add more fields to the table if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic!

```
;with Employees (EmployeeId, HireDate, DepartmentId) as
(
 select 1, getdate()-10, 1 union 
 select 2, getdate()-10, 1 union 
 select 3, getdate()-8, 2 union 
 select 4, getdate()-7, 3 union 
 select 5, getdate()-6, 1  
)
select cast(datepart(year, HireDate) as varchar(4)) + 
 right(replicate('0' ,4)+cast(DepartmentId as varchar(4)), 4) +
 right(replicate('0' ,4)+cast(row_number() over (partition by DepartmentId,datepart(year, HireDate) order by HireDate asc) as varchar(4)), 4) EmployeeCode
 ,DepartmentId
 ,EmployeeId 
 ,convert(varchar(10), HireDate, 120) HireDate
from Employees
```

Will give us the following:

```
EmployeeCode DepartmentId EmployeeId  HireDate
------------ ------------ ----------- ----------
201000010001 1            1           2010-09-05
201000010002 1            2           2010-09-05
201000010003 1            5           2010-09-09
201000020001 2            3           2010-09-07
201000030001 3            4           2010-09-08
```

**UPDATE:**

Now supposing you want to add a new employee to the Department #2 today. Here's how I'd calculate a new EmployeeCode for this employee:

```
declare @DepartmentId int
set @DepartmentId = 2
select 
 cast(datepart(year, getdate()) as varchar(4)) + 
 right(replicate('0' ,4)+cast(@DepartmentId as varchar(4)), 4) +
 right(replicate('0' ,4)+cast(isnull(max(cast(right(EmployeeCode,4) as smallint)),0) + 1 as varchar(4)), 4) EmployeeCode
from dbo.Employees as e
where DepartmentId = @DepartmentId 
and datepart(year, hiredate) = datepart(year, getdate())
```

**UPDATE:**

As you can see, if you add an employee to a hitherto nonexistent department, say, #200, then the max clause would return null as there are no employees in this department and it'd get isnulled to 0 + 1, so you'd get a perfectly normal `201002000001` for that employee.

Suppose a year passed and now it's 2011 and this last filtering clause again would null the max clause and the procedure would repeat and we'd get `201102000001` for a new employee in that new department this next-year.

Comment: When I need to insert a new employee, how would I now what is the next EmpoyeeId to use?

Comment: @Naphtali Davies, you'll have to shred this code and figure out the last one in order to increment the running number.

Comment: Denis, Thanks a lot for your help. Your latest updated doesn't support the need to reset the xxxx part at the begining of each year

Comment: @Naphtali Davies, which latest update? Oh, that's right, you'd want to filter rows based on current year. I'm going to update my last query.

Answer (score 1):

To make your queries easier, you can make the `employeeId` a computed column (which can as well be a `PRIMARY KEY` in `SQL Server`).

I'd suggest you to write a stored procedure to add your employees:

```
CREATE TABLE employee
        (
        employeeId AS
                RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + CAST(year AS VARCHAR), 4) +
                RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + CAST(dept AS VARCHAR), 4) +
                RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + CAST(id AS VARCHAR), 4) PERSISTED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        id INT NOT NULL,
        dept INT NOT NULL,
        year INT NOT NULL,
        CHECK (id BETWEEN 0 AND 9999),
        CHECK (dept BETWEEN 0 AND 9999),
        CHECK (year BETWEEN 0 AND 9999)
        )        
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE prcAddEmployee(@dept INT, @year INT, @employeeId VARCHAR OUT)
AS
        DECLARE @tt TABLE (employeeId VARCHAR(12))
        INSERT
        INTO    employee (id, dept, year)
        OUTPUT  INSERTED.employeeId
        INTO    @tt
        VALUES  (
                (
                SELECT  COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1
                FROM    employee WITH (TABLOCK)
                WHERE   dept = @dept
                        AND year = @year
                ),
                @dept, @year
                )
        SELECT  @employeeId = employeeId
        FROM    @tt
GO
```

Here's a code to check:

```
DECLARE @employeeId VARCHAR(12)
EXEC prcAddEmployee 1, 2010, @employeeId
EXEC prcAddEmployee 1, 2010, @employeeId
EXEC prcAddEmployee 2, 2010, @employeeId
EXEC prcAddEmployee 2, 2010, @employeeId
EXEC prcAddEmployee 1, 2010, @employeeId

SELECT  *
FROM    employee
```

Comment: @Denis: there a slight chance of a race condition (if two queries select `MAX(id)` at the same time before the inserts happen). Of course `PRIMARY KEY` would deal with it but the query would fail instead of waiting. Actually, an `(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` would suffice here, but concurrency is hardly an issue for such a table.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to wrap my head around it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Since xxxx only contains 4 numbers, I don't think this function is heavily used (I mean 100 times or more per second). So I do not think you have to worry about locking and performance too much.

The best approach would be to create a separate table, that contains the latest number given and the year.

Be very careful when updating this table. Check if another client updated the number between when you retrieved it, and want to update it. Use syntax like this:

```
UPDATE xxxxTable
SET number = newNumber
WHERE year = @year and number = @oldnumber
```

Then check for the number of rows updated, if this is not 1, you should create a new number.